What wire size I should go with for a subpanel in a shed 330 ft away?
I am going to put a 80amp breaker on my main panel and wire out to a shed subpanel rated at 100A. The subpanel is about 330 ft away so voltage drop will occur. I'm not as familiar but what wire size should I go with? what about ground wire size? Realistically there will be no more than 4 - 20amp outlets connected to the subpanel but I am just future proofing it.
